# Why do people say that Abraham and his family were idolaters at first?

Tags: avot-patriarch-fathers, avodah-zarah

A common idea these days, is that Abraham, his father and their families were supposed to have worshipped idols, until the true Creator, the LORD, called him from Ur of the Chaldees to give unto him and his seed the promised land (modern day Israel [and indeed much more...]).

Where does this idea come from? Is there proof of it in the Holy Scriptures?

It doesn't make sense to me, since other men which the LORD had 'called out' were all god-fearing men before the LORD called them for their specific purposes. For instance our grandfathers Noah, and Enoch, also kings Saul and David were all reverent to the LORD, and it appears that this is exactly the kind of man He would choose to use for such a great task as Abraham's.

A quote from the [Judaism 101](http://www.jewfaq.org/origins.htm) website:

> Abraham
>
> According to Jewish tradition, Abraham was born under the name Abram
>   in the city of Ur in Babylonia in the year 1948 from Creation (circa
>   1800 BCE). He was the son of Terach, an idol merchant, but from his
>   early childhood, he questioned the faith of his father and sought the
>   truth. He came to believe that the entire universe was the work of a
>   single Creator, and he began to teach this belief to others.
>
> Abram tried to convince his father, Terach, of the folly of idol
>   worship. One day, when Abram was left alone to mind the store, he took
>   a hammer and smashed all of the idols except the largest one. He
>   placed the hammer in the hand of the largest idol. When his father
>   returned and asked what happened, Abram said, "The idols got into a
>   fight, and the big one smashed all the other ones." His father said,
>   "Don't be ridiculous. These idols have no life or power. They can't do
>   anything." Abram replied, "Then why do you worship them?"
>
> Eventually, the one true Creator that Abram had worshipped called to
>   him, and made him an offer: if Abram would leave his home and his
>   family, then G-d would make him a great nation and bless him. Abram
>   accepted this offer, and the b'rit (covenant) between G-d and the
>   Jewish people was established. (Gen. 12).

Comment: You are surprised that God chose someone who wasn't always religious?

Comment: @DoubleAA Not really. The LORD may use whom He pleases. It's just that I would like to know where the argument originated from, and whether we have any proof that it is true, since many people preach it as if it is true.

Comment: Try Joshua 24 verse 2

Comment: If you are looking for (external?) proof, you should specifcy what that entails. Do you want archaeological proof? Old manuscripts? etc.

Comment: @McGafter your question claims that there is a belief that Abraham and not just his father/family worshipped idols. The judaism101 quote says only his father/family. I have yet to see somewhere that claims that Abraham, himself, was an idol worshipper. The only thing I can find (a quote from the Passover Hagaddah) could be read to say that ALL the forefathers worshipped idols so I am checking on that.

Comment: @Danno Thanks. Joshua 24:2 is obviously enough of an explanation to give a possible idea of where the general consensus for it has come from. So I'll accept that as the answer for my purpose. Regarding Abraham's believes; you are right but I would've thought like any child, one starts off in the religion of your parents. Then as you age you begin to see the only true way to God (through Him providing Himself a lamb [Gen22:8]) and either accept it or reject it for idols.

Comment: @McGafter this is from what you quoted: "but from his early childhood, he questioned the faith of his father and sought the truth." Here is a discussion -- early on the refrence to "three years old" is mentioned, as it 40 yrs old. http://vbm-torah.org/archive/bereishit/17bereishit.htm

Comment: @Danno Regarding the Haggadda, R' Yaakov Kaminetzky pointed out that it does not say "mitchila hayu avoseinu ovdei avoda zara" rather "mitchila ovdei avoda zara hayu avoseinu", which means originally idol worshipers were our ancestors, which implies that idol worshipers are no longer our ancestors.  He explains that it refers to Terach, and that our lineage was "spiritually" disconnected and started anew with Avraham.  Thus it never calls Avraham an idol worshiper.

Comment: @McGafter what does "through Him providing Himself a lamb" mean?

Comment: @DovF I think it is very clear from Genesis that Abraham is prophesying, that in the future day from his perspective "God will provide Himself a lamb for a burnt offering" as is stated in the text. The Lamb of God that takes the sins of the World away, since only God can take sins away.

Comment: @McGafter a more accurate translation of ה' יראה לו השה לעולה is "Hashem will see to/for himself the lamb for the burnt offering." In other words, Hashem will choose the lamb. If you insist on your translation, the best understanding of it according to the Hebrew is that God Himself will provide a lamb for a burnt offering. Either way, it was simply what Abraham told Isaac, and yes it was a prophecy as Hashem did indeed choose the lamb -- the ram in the thicket instead of Isaac. From what do you derive that the lamb is something more than that?

Comment: The ram was not a lamb.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Joshua 24:2](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0624.htm)

> Thus said G-d, the L-rd of Israel: your ancestors lived on the other side of the [Euphrates] River from time immemorial; Terach, the father of Abraham and father of Nachor, **and they worshipped foreign gods**

It's a fascinating question (discussed by the classical commentaries in Genesis) exactly when/where humanity took a wrong turn, especially in the chain between Noah and Abraham, but clearly somewhere in the ancestral line there, there were idol worshippers.

(In context: Joshua is warning the people by making it clear that idol worship is in the people's DNA, and if they're not cautious, they'll find themselves sliding back into it -- which is exactly what happened after Joshua died.)

Comment: Actually it's not thus said God the lord of Israel. It's thus said hashem, God of Israel. Which lead to another problem. Why God of universe is repeatedly called God of Israel? http://biblehub.com/text/joshua/24-2.htm

Comment: @J.Chang Correct. Maybe this edit is better. Maybe not. But the four-letter name as it is pronounced does translate to the Lord. Elokei definitely means god, not lord.

Comment: @LN6595 please don't edit others' answers in this manner. This is not a typo; there are different ways of translating the Hebrew, and I'm offering my own translation (you'll see it's more modern-sounding than the JPS I've linked). "The Lord" as a name of God is based on Christian translations, whereas *Aruch HaShulchan* says one could say a bracha to *Gott*. Conversely, *elohim* can also mean "the authorities" or "the mighty"; thus, "God, the Lord of Israel" is an acceptable translation. Others are too, but this is not erroneous.

Comment: http://biblehub.com/text/joshua/24-2.htm it says, yh*h elohei. Seems to mean hashem your god.

Answer (score 1):

This is discussed at length in the first chapter of Hilchos Avodah Zarah, particularly the beginning of Halacha 3:

> בימי אנוש טעו בני האדם טעות גדול ונבערה עצת חכמי אותו הדור ואנוש עצמו
>   מן הטועים היה וזו היתה טעותם אמרו הואיל והאלהים ברא כוכבים אלו וגלגלים
>   להנהיג את העולם ונתנם במרום וחלק להם כבוד והם שמשים המשמשים לפניו
>   ראויין הם לשבחם ולפארם ולחלוק להם כבוד וזהו רצון האל ברוך הוא לגדל
>   ולכבד מי שגדלו וכבדו כמו שהמלך רוצה לכבד העומדים לפניו וזהו כבודו של
>   מלך כיון שעלה דבר זה על לבם התחילו לבנות לכוכבים היכלות ולהקריב להן
>   קרבנות ולשבחם ולפארם בדברים ולהשתחוות למולם כדי להשיג רצון הבורא בדעתם
>   הרעה וזה היה עיקר עבודת כוכבים וכך היו אומרים עובדיה היודעים עיקרה לא
>   שהן אומרים שאין שם אלוה אלא כוכב זה הוא שירמיהו אומר מי לא ייראך מלך
>   הגוים כי לך יאתה כי בכל חכמי הגוים ובכל מלכותם מאין כמוך ובאחת יבערו
>   ויכסלו מוסר הבלים עץ הוא כלומר הכל יודעים שאתה הוא לבדך אבל טעותם
>   וכסילותם שמדמים שזה ההבל רצונך הוא
>
> ואחר שארכו הימים עמדו בבני האדם נביאי שקר ואמרו שהאל צוה ואמר להם עבדו
>   כוכב פלוני או כל הכוכבים והקריבו לו ונסכו לו כך וכך ובנו לו היכל ועשו
>   צורתו כדי להשתחוות לו כל העם הנשים והקטנים ושאר עמי הארץ ומודיע להם
>   צורה שבדה מלבו ואומר זו היא צורת הכוכב פלוני שהודיעוהו בנבואתו והתחילו
>   על דרך זו לעשות צורות בהיכלות ותחת האילנות ובראשי ההרים ועל הגבעות
>   ומתקבצין ומשתחוים להם ואומרים לכל העם שזו הצורה מטיבה ומריעה וראוי
>   לעובדה וליראה ממנה וכהניהם אומרים להם שבעבודה זו תרבו ותצליחו ועשו כך
>   כך ואל תעשו כך וכך והתחילו כוזבים אחרים לעמוד ולומר שהכוכב עצמו או
>   הגלגל או המלאך דבר עמהם ואמר להם עבדוני בכך וכך והודיע להם דרך עבודתו
>   ועשו כך ואל תעשו כך ופשט דבר זה בכל העולם לעבוד את הצורות בעבודות
>   משונות זו מזו ולהקריב להם ולהשתחוות וכיון שארכו הימים נשתכח השם הנכבד
>   והנורא מפי כל היקום ומדעתם ולא הכירוהו ונמצאו כל עם הארץ הנשים והקטנים
>   אינם יודעים אלא הצורה של עץ ושל אבן וההיכל של אבנים שנתחנכו מקטנותם
>   להשתחוות לה ולעבדה ולהשבע בשמה והחכמים שהיו בהם כגון כהניהם וכיוצא בהן
>   מדמין שאין שם אלוה אלא הכוכבים והגלגלים שנעשו הצורות האלו בגללם
>   ולדמותן אבל צור העולמים לא היה שום אדם שהיה מכירו ולא יודעו אלא יחידים
>   בעולם כגון חנוך ומתושלח נח שם ועבר ועל דרך זה היה העולם הולך ומתגלגל
>   עד שנולד עמודו של עולם והוא אברהם אבינו
>
> כיון שנגמל איתן זה התחיל לשוטט בדעתו והוא קטן והתחיל לחשוב ביום ובלילה
>   והיה תמיה היאך אפשר שיהיה הגלגל הזה נוהג תמיד ולא יהיה לו מנהיג ומי
>   יסבב אותו כי אי אפשר שיסבב את עצמו **ולא היה לו מלמד ולא מודיע דבר אלא
>   מושקע באור כשדים בין עובדי כוכבים הטפשים ואביו ואמו וכל העם עובדי
>   כוכבים והוא עובד עמהם ולבו משוטט ומבין** עד שהשיג דרך האמת והבין קו הצדק
>   מתבונתו הנכונה וידע שיש שם אלוה אחד והוא מנהיג הגלגל והוא ברא הכל ואין
>   בכל הנמצא אלוה חוץ ממנו וידע שכל העולם טועים ודבר שגרם להם לטעות זה
>   שעובדים את הכוכבים ואת הצורות עד שאבד האמת מדעתם ובן ארבעים שנה הכיר
>   אברהם את בוראו כיון שהכיר וידע התחיל להשיב תשובות על בני אור כשדים
>   ולערוך דין עמהם ולומר שאין זו דרך האמת שאתם הולכים בה ושיבר הצלמים
>   והתחיל להודיע לעם שאין ראוי לעבוד אלא לאלוה העולם ולו ראוי להשתחוות
>   ולהקריב ולנסך כדי שיכירוהו כל הברואים הבאים וראוי לאבד ולשבר כל הצורות
>   כדי שלא יטעו בהן כל העם כמו אלו שהם מדמים שאין שם אלוה אלא אלו:
>
> כיון שגבר עליהם בראיותיו בקש המלך להורגו ונעשה לו נס ויצא לחרן והתחיל
>   לעמוד ולקרוא בקול גדול לכל העולם ולהודיעם שיש שם אלוה אחד לכל העולם
>   ולו ראוי לעבוד והיה מהלך וקורא ומקבץ העם מעיר לעיר ומממלכה לממלכה עד
>   שהגיע לארץ כנען והוא קורא שנאמר ויקרא שם בשם ה' אל עולם וכיון שהיו העם
>   מתקבצין אליו ושואלין לו על דבריו היה מודיע לכל אחד ואחד כפי דעתו עד
>   שיחזירהו לדרך האמת עד שנתקבצו אליו אלפים ורבבות והם אנשי בית אברהם
>   ושתל בלבם העיקר הגדול הזה וחבר בו ספרים והודיעו ליצחק בנו וישב יצחק
>   מלמד ומזהיר ויצחק הודיע ליעקב ומינהו ללמד וישב מלמד ומחזיק כל הנלוים
>   אליו ויעקב אבינו למד בניו כולם והבדיל לוי ומינהו ראש והושיבו בישבה
>   ללמד דרך השם ולשמור מצות אברהם וצוה את בניו שלא יפסיקו מבני לוי ממונה
>   אחר ממונה כדי שלא תשכח הלמוד והיה הדבר הולך ומתגבר בבני יעקב ובנלוים
>   עליהם ונעשית בעולם אומה שהיא יודעת את ה' עד שארכו הימים לישראל במצרים
>   וחזרו ללמוד מעשיהן ולעבוד כוכבים כמותן חוץ משבט לוי שעמד במצות אבות
>   ומעולם לא עבד שבט לוי עבודת כוכבים וכמעט קט היה העיקר ששתל אברהם נעקר
>   וחוזרין בני יעקב לטעות העולם ותעיותן ומאהבת ה' אותנו ומשמרו את השבועה
>   לאברהם אבינו עשה משה רבינו רבן של כל הנביאים ושלחו כיון שנתנבא משה
>   רבינו ובחר ה' ישראל לנחלה הכתירן במצות והודיעם דרך עבודתו ומה יהיה
>   משפט עבודת כוכבים וכל הטועים אחריה
>
> During the times of Enosh, mankind made a great mistake, and the wise
>   men of that generation gave thoughtless counsel. Enosh himself was one
>   of those who erred.
>
> Their mistake was as follows: They said God created stars and spheres
>   with which to control the world. He placed them on high and treated
>   them with honor, making them servants who minister before Him.
>   Accordingly, it is fitting to praise and glorify them and to treat
>   them with honor. [They perceived] this to be the will of God, blessed
>   be He, that they magnify and honor those whom He magnified and
>   honored, just as a king desires that the servants who stand before him
>   be honored. Indeed, doing so is an expression of honor to the king.
>
> After conceiving of this notion, they began to construct temples to
>   the stars and offer sacrifices to them. They would praise and glorify
>   them with words, and prostrate themselves before them, because by
>   doing so, they would - according to their false conception - be
>   fulfilling the will of God.
>
> This was the essence of the worship of false gods, and this was the
>   rationale of those who worshiped them. They would not say that there
>   is no other god except for this star.
>
> This message was conveyed by Jeremiah, who declared (10:7-8): "Who
>   will not fear You, King of the nations, for to You it is fitting.
>   Among all the wise men of the nations and in all their kingdoms, there
>   is none like You. They have one foolish and senseless [notion. They
>   conceive of their] empty teachings as wood;" i.e., all know that You
>   alone are God. Their foolish error consists of conceiving of this
>   emptiness as Your will.
>
> After many years passed, there arose people - false prophets - who
>   told [their nations] that God had commanded them to say: Serve this
>   star - or all the stars - sacrifice to it, offer libations to it,
>   build a temple for it and make an image of it so that all people -
>   including the women, the children, and the common people - could bow
>   to it.
>
> He would inform them of a form that he had conceived, and tell them
>   that this is the image of the particular star, claiming that this was
>   revealed to him in a prophetic vision. In this manner, the people
>   began to make images in temples, under trees, and on the tops of
>   mountains and hills.
>
> People would gather together and bow down to them and the [false
>   prophets] would say: This image is the source of benefit or harm. It
>   is appropriate to serve it and fear it. Their priests would tell them:
>   This service will enable you to multiply and be successful. Do this
>   and this, or do not do this or this.
>
> Subsequently, other deceivers arose and declared that a specific star,
>   sphere, or angel had spoken to them and commanded them: Serve me in
>   this manner. He would then relate a mode of service [telling them:] Do
>   this, do not do this.
>
> Thus, these practices spread throughout the world. People would serve
>   images with strange practices - one more distorted than the other -
>   offer sacrifices to them, and bow down to them. As the years passed,
>   [God's] glorious and awesome name was forgotten by the entire
>   population. [It was no longer part of] their speech or thought, and
>   they no longer knew Him. Thus, all the common people, the women, and
>   the children would know only the image of wood or stone and the
>   temples of stone to which they were trained from their childhood to
>   bow down and serve, and in whose name they swore.
>
> The wise men among them would think that there is no God other than
>   the stars and spheres for whose sake, and in resemblance of which,
>   they had made these images. The Eternal Rock was not recognized or
>   known by anyone in the world, with the exception of a [few]
>   individuals: for example, Chanoch, Metushelach, Noach, Shem, and Ever.
>   The world continued in this fashion until the pillar of the world -
>   the Patriarch Abraham - was born.
>
> After this mighty man was weaned, he began to explore and think.
>   Though he was a child, he began to think [incessantly] throughout the
>   day and night, wondering: How is it possible for the sphere to
>   continue to revolve without having anyone controlling it? Who is
>   causing it to revolve? Surely, it does not cause itself to revolve.
>
> **He had no teacher, nor was there anyone to inform him. Rather, he was
>   mired in Ur Kasdim among the foolish idolaters. His father, mother,
>   and all the people [around him] were idol worshipers, and he would
>   worship with them. [However,] his heart was exploring and [gaining]
>   understanding.**
>
> Ultimately, he appreciated the way of truth and understood the path of
>   righteousness through his accurate comprehension. He realized that
>   there was one God who controlled the sphere, that He created
>   everything, and that there is no other God among all the other
>   entities. He knew that the entire world was making a mistake. What
>   caused them to err was their service of the stars and images, which
>   made them lose awareness of the truth.
>
> Abraham was forty years old when he became aware of his Creator. When
>   he recognized and knew Him, he began to formulate replies to the
>   inhabitants of Ur Kasdim and debate with them, telling them that they
>   were not following a proper path.
>
> He broke their idols and began to teach the people that it is fitting
>   to serve only the God of the world. To Him [alone] is it fitting to
>   bow down, sacrifice, and offer libations, so that the people of future
>   [generations] would recognize Him. [Conversely,] it is fitting to
>   destroy and break all the images, lest all the people err concerning
>   them, like those people who thought that there are no other gods
>   besides these [images].
>
> When he overcame them through the strength of his arguments, the king
>   desired to kill him. He was [saved through] a miracle and left for
>   Charan. [There,] he began to call in a loud voice to all people and
>   inform them that there is one God in the entire world and it is proper
>   to serve Him. He would go out and call to the people, gathering them
>   in city after city and country after country, until he came to the
>   land of Canaan - proclaiming [God's existence the entire time] - as
>   [Genesis 21:33] states: "And He called there in the name of the Lord,
>   the eternal God."
>
> When the people would gather around him and ask him about his
>   statements, he would explain [them] to each one of them according to
>   their understanding, until they turned to the path of truth.
>   Ultimately, thousands and myriads gathered around him. These are the
>   men of the house of Abraham.
>
> He planted in their hearts this great fundamental principle, composed
>   texts about it, and taught it to Isaac, his son. Isaac also taught
>   others and turned [their hearts to God]. He also taught Jacob and
>   appointed him as a teacher.
>
> [Jacob] taught others and turned [the hearts] of all those who
>   gathered around him [to God]. He also taught all of his children. He
>   selected Levi and appointed him as the leader. He established him [as
>   the head of] the academy to teach them the way of God and observe the
>   mitzvot of Abraham.
>
> [Jacob] commanded his sons that the leadership should not depart from
>   the descendants of Levi, so that the teachings would not be forgotten.
>   This concept proceeded and gathered strength among the descendants of
>   Jacob and those who collected around them, until there became a nation
>   within the world which knew God.
>
> When the Jews extended their stay in Egypt, however, they learned from
>   the [Egyptians'] deeds and began worshiping the stars as they did,
>   with the exception of the tribe of Levi, who clung to the mitzvot of
>   the patriarchs - the tribe of Levi never served false gods.
>
> Within a short time, the fundamental principle that Abraham had
>   planted would have been uprooted, and the descendants of Jacob would
>   have returned to the errors of the world and their crookedness.
>   Because of God's love for us, and to uphold the oath He made to
>   Abraham, our patriarch, He brought forth Moses, our teacher, the
>   master of all prophets, and sent him [to redeem the Jews]. After
>   Moses, our teacher, prophesied, and God chose Israel as His
>   inheritance, He crowned them with mitzvot and informed them of the
>   path to serve Him, [teaching them] the judgement prescribed for idol
>   worshiper and all those who stray after it.